# Integrate TCPDF in Printing Invoice PDF : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, tcpdf

How can I use `TCPDF` in print Invoice PDF, Really I am facing a problem which is Arabic characters are reversed and separated.

I did a search a lot for this problem and found `Zen PDF` has many problems with fonts, so there are many advices to use `TCPDF`.

Kindly help.